# If dharma protects one then how could unrighteous people like Alauddin Khilji win so many times?

Tags: krishna, dharma, adharma

If god protects people who follow dharma then how could unrighteous man like Alauddin Khilji win against so many Hindu kings who used to follow dharma, who always had god in their mind,followed scriptures were killed by Khilji.If it was one or two ruler it might would have been understandable but so many kings, their countrymen were killed by him,him being an unrighteous person not following dharma, living up to a good age,not believing in krishna?